Google Calendar: Creating an event in a different calendar makes a copy of it in the primary one
I'm using googleapis on Next.js to create calendar events for booking meetings.
For that purpose I created a calendar in my Google account in which I only want to have those bookings.
However the events are created well, I get the event in my specifically created calendar but a duplicate of it is also created in my primary Google calendar.
I don't know if this is the way Google is supposed to work, but I would like that booking only to be created in the extra calendar.
This is the function that creates the event (using Next.js 14.x)

export async function createCalendarEvent({
  clerkUserId,
  durationInMinutes,
  eventName,
  guestEmail,
  guestName,
  guestNotes,
  startTime,
}: {
  clerkUserId: string;
  durationInMinutes: number;
  eventName: string;
  guestEmail: string;
  guestName: string;
  guestNotes?: string | null;
  startTime: Date;
}) {
  const oAuthClient = await getOAuthClient(clerkUserId);
  const calendarUser = await clerkClient().users.getUser(clerkUserId);

  if (calendarUser.primaryEmailAddress == null) {
    throw new Error("Clerk user has no email");
  }

  const calendarEvent = await google.calendar("v3").events.insert({
    calendarId: process.env.GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID,
    auth: oAuthClient,
    sendUpdates: "all",
    requestBody: {
      attendees: [
        { email: guestEmail, displayName: guestName },
        {
          email: calendarUser.primaryEmailAddress.emailAddress,
          displayName: calendarUser.fullName,
          responseStatus: "accepted",
        },
      ],
      description: guestNotes ? `Additional Details: ${guestNotes}` : undefined,
      start: {
        dateTime: startTime.toISOString(),
      },
      end: {
        dateTime: addMinutes(startTime, durationInMinutes).toISOString(),
      },
      summary: `${guestName} + ${calendarUser.fullName}: ${eventName}`,
    },
  });

  return calendarEvent.data;
}

Is it possible to have the event created only in the specific calendar for which I gave the calendarId? Or where I'm doing something wrong?
For the sake of clarity, here's a screenshot of the double booking


Kindly share what's in process.env.GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID.

That's not the issue. The variable is fine and the event is created

Understood. I asked for that because that's where the calendarId is stored, which is the parameter of Events: insert, and if either the word primary or your email address is on it, that could be the cause of the issue you're experiencing. If everything's in order and the issue persists, I recommend that you consider submitting a bug report to let Google know about the unusual behavior that's going on.

Apologies as well. What I meant with the comment is the configurations of the .ENV file, not the actual variable value.

Also, for any sensitive information, such as API keys, you may redact them since only the configurations are what's needed to be checked for any underlying issue.
